# В третьем условии, по идее должно дописываться 1 справа, но выдает ошибку. Программа правильно написана, помогите только с третьим условием

Tags: python

```
def f(x, end):
    if x > end:
        return 0
    if x == end:
        return 1
    return f(x + 2, end) + f(x + 3, end) + f(x + '1', end)
print(f(3,12) * f(12,25))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы зачем строки с числами пытаетесь сложить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите "приписать справа" к целому числу одну цифру, то просто умножьте это число на 10 и прибавьте нужную цифру:

```py
f(x*10 + 1, end)
```

А так просто числа со строками "складывать" нельзя, тем более если в итоге нужно получить опять число. Правильно будет что-то такое тогда, если хотите именно таким способом:

```py
f(int(str(x) + '1'), end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка пишет следующее: операция сложения для операндов типа 'int' и 'str' невозможна

Чтобы складывать всё как строки, вам нужно явно преобразовать данные в строки посредством функции

`str(num)`

Где `num` - ваша переменная.

Чтобы "дописать" числу справа единицу, можно поступить странновато, но интуитивно +/- понятно:

`int(str(x) + '1')`

То есть такие шаги (допустим, `x = 28` изначально):

1. `str(x)`: 28 -> '28'
2. `str(x) + '1'`: '28' -> '281'
3. `int(str(x) + '1')`: '281' -> 281

Но я бы посоветовал воспользоваться знаниями математики и применить следующее:

`x * 10 + 1`: 28 -> 281

Как-то так

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x, end):
    if x > end:
        return 0
    if x == end:
        return 1
    return f(x + 2, end) + f(x + 3, end) + f(x + 1, end)
print(f(3,12) * f(12,25))
```

У вас 1 тип str, в ошибке об этом явно написано

Comment: Так это "f(x + 1, end)"просто добавит 1 к x, а мне нужно дописать к нему единицу

Comment: Напишите пример того, что ожидаете

Comment: def f(x, end):
    if x > end:
        return 0
    if x == end:
        return 1
    return f(x + 2, end) + f(x + 3, end) + f(int(str(x) + '1'), end)
print(f(3,12) * f(12,25))

Answer (score 0):

Давай-те обратим внимание на то что нам пишет компилятор:

```
unsupported operand type(s), for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Мы не можем сложить **int** и **str**. Это как огонь с водой - ничего не выйдет. Python не может складывать int и str. Все по отдельности - str складывается с str, int складывается с int. Это было во-первых.

А во-вторых, в коде допущена ошибка. Почему в третьем действии на 6 строке значение типа **str**? Вот вам и решение проблемы. На всякий случай код:

```
def f(x, end):
    if x > end:
        return 0
    if x == end:
        return 1
    return f(x + 2, end) + f(x + 3, end) + f(x + 1, end)
print(f(3,12) * f(12,25))
```

Вот вам и решение проблемы :)

Comment: Думаю, он хотел, чтоб справа единичка "приклеивалась" к числу, отсюда и такая странная операция

Comment: Возможно, но тогда надо всю левую часть переводить в str и уже потом приклеивать. Также и с переменной x в третьем действии.

UPD: Плюс, условие неправильно дано. От сюда и непонятно, чего именно нужно.